# Not able to install the lastest version of Teamviewer on my Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04

I am having trouble installing latest version of Teamviewer.

```
root@naveena:~# sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux_x64.deb
dpkg: error processing teamviewer_linux_x64.deb (--install):
cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
teamviewer_linux_x64.deb
```

Comment: `dpkg -i /path/teamviewer_linux_x64.deb`

Answer (score 3):

Working on your computer as root is not a good idea; you can easliy ruin your system. I would use `sudo` instead.

You are getting the error message because the path is incorrect; you are trying to install it from `~#`, which refers to the `root` directory, since you are logged in as root. That is most certainly not where the file is located.

I think you are making it unnecessarily complicated: you can run the installer (teamviewer_linux_x64.deb) by double clicking (from your own user account), the Software Center will ask you for your password.

***If*** you want to install it from the command line, again, do that from your own user account.
Either cd to the path first, like:

```
~$ cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux_x64.deb
```

or enter the full path:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/teamviewer_linux_x64.deb
```

(assuming the file is in the Downloads folder)